# Save string from separate .txt file to variable

Tags: c, command-line-arguments

Using command-line arguments, I ultimately am going to 'censor' a string from stdin by replacing each one word text string argument (argv[1], argv[2], .. ) with the word 'CENSORED', copying the new censored text to stdout. Until now, I've learned how to determine if one argument is in the other, that is,

```
if( strstr(argv[1], argv[2]) != NULL ) // Argument 1 contains argument 2
```

But I would like to know if argv[i] is in Input.txt. I am having trouble accessing and comparing command-line arguments with the input string.

How does one access and save a string from Input.txt into a variable to be manipulated in a C program?

Comment: And why are you having problems, where exactly does your code fail?

Comment: Read the content into an appropriately sized buffer (potentially expanding if needed), terminate the buffer with a final `'\0'` to fulfill the requirement as a terminated string, then use said-buffer for your searches. That pretty much sums it up.

Comment: Lookup `fopen`, `fgets`, `fscanf` and `fclose`.